# udev rule doesn't work

Tags: arch-linux, systemd, udev

I want to learn more about udev rules, so I implemented a simple one, but I doesn't work:

*/etc/udev/rules.d:*

```
KERNEL=="sdb1"
ACTION=="add"

RUN+="~/test/exe.sh"
```

*~/test/exe.sh:*

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "USB plugged in" > ~/test/showup.txt
```

the `.sh` file is executable, and I checked the flash drive's name via `lsblk`. It is called `sdb` and has a `sdb1` partition.

I already looked up different tutorials, but can't find my mistake. I use Arch Linux in case that matters.

Comment: Aside from any other issue, udev knows nothing about `~`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

udev rules execute by root.

The RUN+="~/test/exe.sh" equals "/root/test/exe.sh", but udev rules seems not recognize the "~"; modify the path will solve this issue.

put your script such in "/usr/bin/exe.sh" might be better.

Comment: Or given that it's run as root he can just use the absolute original path instead.

Comment: Agreed, your advice also solve this question.

Comment: I noticed it is also working in my home directory if I use the absolute path, but I have to call the file `exe.sh` even though I specify it in the udev rule as `exe`. Why is it automatically adding the suffix `.sh` to the file it looks for? Or do I understand something wrong?